# Pass data to another view controller in navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have two view controllers (fitstViewController.swift and secondViewController.swift) in navigation controler.

My idea is that
In firstViewController there are a button and a textFIeld. When I click the button, value in the textField is passed to secondViewController.

However it makes an error "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" in the first controller.

Here is the code in the first controller..

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController

    let detailController = destination.topViewController as! secondViewController

    detailController.stockSymbol = textField.text
}
```

I added just one line in the second controller..

```
    var stockSymbol:String!
```

How can it be solved?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your old code by:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    guard let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? SecondViewController else { return } 
    destination.stockSymbol = textField.text
}
```

Comment: As the commentary below from @Apps-wise, you should also not force unwrap `SecondViewController`: Always make a check: `guard let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? SecondViewController else { return }
  destination.stockSymbol = textField.text`

Answer (score 3):

In second controller the declared variable should be

```
 var stockSymbol:String?
```

You should not force unwrap it unless you are sure that it would never be nil.